# Deferred WPF GridSplitter

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, grid, gridsplitter

Hello All
Does anyone know if you can have a deferred GridSplitter resize in the same fashion as the scollviewer
eg

```
ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you like [ShowsPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridsplitter.showspreview.aspx) = false; ?